# how do i see the logs of force.com in eclipse?

Tags: force.com

I changed the code in force eclipse and want to check the logs or console panel to see what happening in the background for that how will i see that logs in eclipse .

Let you know, I have setup all the code from salesforce enviornment to eclipse.Now i am making changes and it is working fine but eclipse shortcut is not working.

Comment: Check if you have added correct user in debug logs for monitoring.

Comment: you should really edit the question to make it clear what you are asking.  Per your comments on an answer you are saying to ignore parts.  Please update the question to reflect your true question so it is clear

Comment: Are you asking for the logs of what is happening in eclipse (and when it sends code to salesforce) or logs of what happens when you execute the code/pages in salesforce ? (that you've build in eclipse)

Comment: As others have mentioned, you need to make this question clearer. No one knows what you are really asking.

Answer (score 1):

@amit, i don't get what do you mean by "eclipse shortcut's not working" but to see logs, i think you ld write a test class,

@isTest
public class UnitTest {
//call a method which returns something and then system.debug it
system.debug(MyClasss.myMethod());
}

run the test and see the logs in force ide,

Comment: Forget that shortcut problem.

Comment: Actually We have developed a application on salesforce enviornment using apex programming and that code i connected to eclipse to make changes when i am running that app on salesforce enviorment then i am unable to locate the logs in eclipse or in salesforce .

Comment: @amit, the developer console's your friend, just run the tests from there, you'll see the results at the bottom, d-click them and you will see the logs, you just need do to some unit tests, to see the logs, because force<dot>com has no main method. And if you make some changes via web ide, don't forget to refresh that in eclipse, before running the tests